# Caching The Time Stamp

Tags: file, caching, timestamp, stat

I have a project in which i am creating a file and also getting the file creation time using:-

```
stat("C:/repos/trunk/logging/test.log",&attrib);
```

i want to cache the last time stamp so that i do not take this on every log message.

Please offer help.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "cache the last timestamp"?  Whatever it is you want to cache, why don't you just store it in a variable?

Comment: i just want to cache it , so that i need not hit on every log message ,also storing in a variable would be like string date1//a variable declared as global or something like this that i have done:-

    stat("C:/repos/trunk/logging/test.log",&attrib);
    clock = gmtime(&(attrib.st_ctime));

Comment: Well, you *could* use a global, but you should try to find a way to avoid it.  But whatever you do, it will involve storing the information *somewhere*.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth somesuggetsions from u r side searching for a long time about

Answer (score 0):

`stat` doesn't give you file creation time. It gives you file modification time, access time, and inode change time.

You can certainly cache that information if you want, subject to the normal issues of caching, that is, you run the risk of having stale data in the cache if the file is modified and you don't check again soon enough.

If your program is single-threaded and you are only dealing with one file, you could use a `static` variable for example. Otherwise you might want to create an object (in the OO sense) that keeps the cached timestamp and a TTL for the cached value as internal state, and offers methods to query and/or refresh the value.

Comment: :i was checking out the stat functionality and it showed that by using the:-
        stat("C:/repos/trunk/logging/test.log",&attrib); 
        clock = gmtime(&(attrib.st_ctime));//st_ctime gives the creation time,i wont say it is single threaded however i am currently dealing with a single file

Comment: No, [`st_ctime` is the inode change time](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html). This means the time when attributes of the file (such as permissions, timstamps, extended attributes, etc...) were last changed, as opposed to `st_mtime` which is the time when the _contents_ of the file were last changed.

Comment: :so if i just need to have the time when the file was just created then what should i use for that?and give some suggestions of soring the time somewhere ...

Comment: I gave some suggestions for storing the time. As for how to get the creation time, no such functionality exists in POSIX (`stat` is a POSIX function). But you seem to be using MS Windows, and no doubt there is a non-portable OS-specific way to get file creation time under that operation system. But I know very little about MS Windows and I don't know what that function might be.